# z-index does not work on my tooltip with carousel

Tags: html, css, hover, tooltip, carousel

On the carousel at the top of my [site](http://exerion.comule.com/prochaine.html), I am using two sorts of tooltip.
The first is the one implemented with the carousel which uses this style:

```
  #carousel div:hover span,
        #carousel div.hover span {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 500px;
            padding: 2px 0;
            margin: 0 0 0 -500px;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 50%;
            border-radius: 3px;
            z-index: 600 !important;
        }
```

This the grey box, as you can see with the first image, if it goes over the wrapper div, it will cut it. Even though I am using z-index.

The second is the one which use the class "tooltip4" :

```
.tooltip4:hover em {
z-index: 600;
text-align: center;
font-style: normal;
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
left: 50px;
padding: 5px;
color: #fff;
/*border: 1px solid #bbb;*/
background-color:rgba(16,110,99,0.9);
box-shadow: 0 0 7px 2px #1B8478;
width:400px;    
}
```

This one is used on the second image, and you can't even see it, it should have an effect similar to the carousel in the left.

Is there a solution to these problems please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#carousel div:hover span,#carousel div.hover span {margin: 0 0 0 -90px;}
```

remove z-index from this class `#carousel div`

and edit this class

```
.tooltip4:hover em {top: -243px;left: -197px;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I can indeed see the second tooltip now but it will still be cut off at the bottom because of the `overflow: hidden`. If possible I would like it to appear outside of the header.

Comment: you can use position:fixed for this and off-course change the top and left values according to your need

Comment: Thanks so much, it works. But It is still cut off with firefox .

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is actually that you've placed your `span` within `div.caroufredsel_wrapper` which has specific width and height so it is getting cut off outside of that `div`.  If you place the span at a higher level (like under `body` or maybe `header` or `div#wrapper`), it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the `div.caroufredsel_wrapper` width seems to be the same as the `wrapper` one. The reasons I can't see the tooltip seems to be because of the overflow, but event if I make it visible with CSS: I will be able to see the tooltip but the images will overflow as well when sliding. I don't know how to place the `span` at a higher level, since its for each image (unless you are talking about the z-index level).